# Unique Contact ID

Tags: android, android-contacts

Does android assign unique constant IDs to every contact?
If not, is there a way to assign such information to them?
Could I sync this ID to google contacts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve unique ids for only synced Google contacts. In other cases you may get different ids as in Android raw_id of every contact is changed whenever user resets or re-imports contacts to phone-book.

If you want consistency in contact-ids irrespective of device, platform then either use only synced Google contacts or write your own work around code to generate unique ids for e.g.  get hash of contact's number,name etc which rarely changes

Answer (score 3):

There are two type of contact ids in the android contacts.

one is **CONTACT_ID** ans other is **RAW_CONTACT_ID**

Refer this tutorial.
[ANDROID CONTACTS](http://android-contact-id-vs-raw-contact-id.blogspot.in/)

hope this will help you.

Comment: But I don't think that these IDs will be constant if I sync them to an other device that is linked to my google account.
Is there a way to sync user defined data with my google contacts?

Comment: of course not. it is the unique ids within the android device only.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question: Does android assign unique constant IDs to every contact? Yes or no?

Answer (score 1):

```
ContactsContract.RawContacts    SOURCE_ID
```

> A string value that uniquely identifies this raw contact to the
>   account in which it was created
>
> When a sync adapter creates a new raw contact, this column should be
>   set to the server's unique ID for the raw contact. When an Android
>   application creates a new raw contact, the application should leave
>   this column empty. This signals the sync adapter that it should create
>   a new raw contact on the server, and get a value for the SOURCE_ID. In
>   particular, the source id must be unique for each account type and
>   should be stable across syncs:
>
> Unique: Each raw contact for an account must have its own source id.
>   If you don't enforce this, you'll cause problems in the contacts
>   application. Notice that two raw contacts for the same account type
>   may have the same source id. For example, the raw contact "Thomas
>   Higginson" for the account emily.dickinson@gmail.com is allowed to
>   have the same source id as the raw contact "Thomas Higginson" for the
>   account emilyd@gmail.com. Stable: Source ids are a permanent part of
>   the online service's data for the raw contact. For example, if the
>   user clears Contacts Storage from the Apps settings and re-syncs, the
>   restored raw contacts should have the same source ids as before. If
>   you don't enforce this, shortcuts will stop working.

Here is the official doc: [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Answer (score -2):

There is the LOOKUP_KEY column exactly for this purpose.

While documentation is scarse it seems to be persistent in between new installs and different phones.

Documentation: [LOOKUP_KEY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns#LOOKUP_KEY)

Comment: I don't think this is accurate, from my experimentation it looks like this key changes on contacts updates. It also a composed key, so if the contact get's merged with a skype contact for example the key will change.

Comment: Yes it's composed, but its parts remain the same. You can split it up using the dots in between the parts and match the parts again.
How are you editing the contact? When changing, name number and mail the lookup stays the same for me...